# How do I create a DatatSet with Data Type: ModelDirectory in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I'm attempting to manually create a DataSet with Data Type: ModelDirectory in Azure Machine Learning Studio, in order to use it in an Inference Pipeline.  I have taken an existing ModelDirectory DataSet and attempted to replicate it.  Everything is identical, *except* that the replica has Data Type:  AnyDirectory, and can not be hooked up to the input of a ScoreModel node in the designer.  How can I (manually in the UI or, better yet, programmatically) create a DataSet with Data Type: ModelDirectory from the output files of a trained model?

Existing DataSet:
[image]
Existing DataSet outputs:
[image]

Manually Created Replica DataSet:
[image]
Manually Created Replica DataSet outputs:
[image]

As you can see, the outputs of both DataSets are *identical*.  The only difference between the two DataSets, seems to be the 'Data Type' properties, although in the output view, you can see that both have 'type: ModelDirectory'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spent a few hours on this exact problem. To save anyone else the wasted time: it looks like you cannot create a dataset with ModelDirectory type in Azure ML SDK V2.

On Microsoft's support site, another user had this exact problem, and filed a support ticket (thread here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/398468/how-do-i-create-a-modeldirectory-type-filedataset). Microsoft directly told them that this is not something exposed to users.

Reproducing the post here in case the link goes down (emphasis mine):

> I managed to take this all the way to the Microsoft product development team, and the answer (paraphrased) was as follows. **This ModelDirectory class is 100% abstracted from the users, and thus cannot be called from with a user defined block.**
>
> The group told me that **the designer is not meant to be a production grade tool in it's current implemention** - more of a prototyping tool - and it is not compatible with CI/CD processes like python scripts are. Automated retraining in the designer is not a supported scenario as of today either, since we can't create an API for the training pipeline. I can't speak to the roadmap though, but I did advocate that some method of enabling automation and MLOps in the designer would be highly desirable.
>
> So I don't think you're missing anything. In the end we had to work with the team to convert the prototyped pipelines into python equivalents.

Which is a real shame, because Azure ML is otherwise a pretty okay system. Ultimately what I did was what the post's author did: I wrote my own versions of the nodes I wanted to use.